# Default gestures being called on a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom `UIButton` on my `view`.

Do you know if any "default" actions are being called for this button
when the button is first loaded (e.g., say during `willMoveToSuperview`, or in `viewDidLoad`?)?

For example, maybe `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event is called?? or some other event??.

Comment: That's not likely to happen, as those kind of events respond to user interaction and not when you move it around.
What kind of problem are you having??

Comment: When the button gets loaded, I want it to be displayed with a selected state. This sometimes happens, sometimes not. So, I had a suspicion that somewhere in these gesture recognizers maybe an action is called which "removes" the "selected" state from my button .....

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing od this nature is supposed to happen: buttons have no "default actions", and most certainly these could not be called behind your back in `viewDidLoad`. On the other hand, you are free to call the corresponding `IBAction` methods manually.

> When the button gets loaded, I want it to be displayed with a selected state.

The best place to ensure that that happens is `viewWillAppear` method.